# How is the WiFi Security Protocol (WPA, WPA2, etc) Determined from Network Beacons?

Tags: linux, wifi, netlink, wpa-supplicant

I know APs and surrounding networks send out Beacon Frames periodically which contain information about themselves. This can include Capability Information, RSN etc... What information from the Beacon is used to determine the method of encryption used on the network? I have seen examples already implemented on supplicants like wpa_supplicant or simple android apps.. but I'm not sure of the specific information given within the Beacon which determines the exact method of encryption protocol used?

Comment: Seems like you should read the relevant standards to determine the exact processes. But unless you're implementing a WiFi receiver, this isn't a programming question.

Comment: In fact, it's a feature I'm currently working on. I've looked at code on the wpa_supplicant repo and it seems to parse all the beacon IES and decides on the encryption protocol used by so network. I'm wondering at the specific information that gets looked at within the beacon and the deciding factor that figures out the encryption method.